# NSSet full of NSStrings. When I print the set to the console, the results are unexpected

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Here's what happens:**

*Internal database stuff:* one class has a string property on it, that stores a phone number. This number is set using the code

```
CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty), 0));
```

*My function:* finds all objects of this type, and stores phone numbers of each object in an NSMutableSet.

*Debug:* I print the description of the set to the console.

**Results:**

- Some of the set's objects look as expected (the majority actually): "+64 27 0124 975"
- Some are missing quotation marks: 027 7824 565
- Some have weird unicode symbols: "021\U00a0026\U00a017788"

**My question:**

Why the difference - what does it mean, and do I need to fix anything?

Comment: don't worry about the debug description of objects...

Comment: Perfectly normal.  The `description` method on the collection objects does several unexpected things.  Eg, strings with no "special" characters are not enclosed in quotes, and Unicode values greater than 0x7F are displayed in escaped form.  Also, often newline characters get converted to `\n` and several other such transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog with `%@` – as I assume you are using – has some intelligence in how it presents NSStrings as it calls the description method. If the string has anything other than alphanumerics, such as the '+' or '\' above, it will use quotes. The string with unicode characters simply has its characters encoded as shown, and they are automatically converted into this lossless format. You should be able to convert it to something prettier for the console if you really need to with something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithCString:[myString.description cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding]);
```